# Formatting "Bond, JAMES (Mr)"

Tags: java, performance, strings, formatting

I need to call this function over a big dataset. I need it to be as efficient as possible but still be readable. Can I make it anymore efficient by using a different function for capitalize or blank check?

```
public static String nameFormat(String title, String firstname, String lastName) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(firstname) && StringUtils.isBlank(lastName)) {
        return "Unknown";
    }

    StringBuilder fullNameSB = new StringBuilder(lastName.trim().toUpperCase());
    fullNameSB.append(", ");
    fullNameSB.append(WordUtils.capitalizeFully(firstname.trim()));
    if (title != null) {
        fullNameSB.append(" ");
        // replace (mr.) with mr
        title = title.trim().replaceAll("\\.|\\)|\\(", "");
        fullNameSB.append("(");
        fullNameSB.append(WordUtils.capitalize(title));
        fullNameSB.append(")");
    }
    //Remove any double spaces that might be in a multipart first or surname
    return fullNameSB.toString().replaceAll("  ", "");

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume `WordUtils` and `StringUtils` are Apache Commons?  If so, it would be helpful for us for you to link to their online documentation/source.

The first thing to do when optimizing is to make sure you're optimizing the right thing.  You might find ways to shave off a bit of running time in this method, but if this method is only responsible for 1% of the total running time then that's not very good use of your effort.

The thing that strikes me is all of the safety for weird conditions.  I can pretty much guarantee you that your `replaceAll` calls are the slowest things.  Maybe upstream code should be ensuring that the `title` is of the correct form to begin with, the strings are trimmed, and there are no double spaces.